# SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, sql-server

I was running some Python script where it has to connect to Microsoft SQL and execute some query.
I ran this script before and everything worked fine, however between these 2 times I reinstalled Anaconda 3 (Python 3.5) (not sure if it's related).
But this time when I tried to run this script, first time it pops up an error "no module pyodbc exists", so I went for installing pyodbc here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. After installing pyodbc, this error pops up and I just can't go over it..
It's my first time posting here so if I miss any details please let me know.
HELP!!Thanks.

Comment: did you activate the correct virtual environment?

Comment: If you are using anaconda, you should install with `conda install pyodbc` rather than pulling in a precompiled binary from elsewhere.